# Printing Integers from Self Defined Linked List

Tags: java, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Below is a sample test question that I am completely lost on and have no clue how to answer.

> "You are given a text file containing a series of integers in ascending order. Write a complete program to print the contents of the file out in reverse order. You must use a linked list to hold the contents of the file, and you must define your own linked list classes. Do not use the Java API LinkedList implementations."

**My Question Is:**

I have the following (working) code, but does this definition fill the requirements for the above question? And if yes, how would I use it to print integers. If No, what do I have to add replace to make it work?

```
public class Node {
    String value;
    Node next;

    public Node(String s) {
        this.value = s;
        next = null;
    }

    public Node(String s, Node n) {
        this.value = s;
        this.next = n;
    }

    public void setValue(String newValue) { //setters
        this.value = newValue;
    }
    public void setNext(Node newNext) {
        this.next = newNext;
    }

    public String getValue() { // getters
        return this.value;
    }
    public Node getNext() {
        return this.next;
    }
}
```

Comment: well it doesn't print anything or read a file or implement a linked list, so it doesn't fulfill the assignment, but it can be probably used as a part of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.File;

class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        LinkedList ll = new LinkedList();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("yourFile.txt"));
        int i = 0;
        while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
            ll.drive(sc.nextInt());
            i++;// Number of integers
        }
        ll.printing(i);
    }
}

class LinkedList {

    static int arr[];
    Node head;
    static Node ahead = null;// This node has all the nodes merged(see drive() function) forming a linked list.
    
    static class Node {

        int data;
        Node next;
    }

    static Node newNode(int data) {
        Node nn = new Node();
        nn.data = data;
        nn.next = null;
        return nn;
    }

    static Node insertEnd(Node head, int data) {
        if (head == null) {
            return newNode(data);
        } else {
            head.next = insertEnd(head.next, data);
        }
        return head;
    }

    public static void drive(int arg) {
        ahead = insertEnd(ahead, arg);
    }

    static void printing(int i) {
        if (ahead == null) {
            return;
        }
        //Storing in reverse
        arr = new int[i];

        for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--, ahead = ahead.next) {
            arr[j] = ahead.data;
        }

        //Printing in reverse
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            System.out.println(arr[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks so much, I just wanted to ask what the purpose of the drive method is?

Comment: The drive function is continuously called from the main function (while loop) for each integer .drive function is used to continuously add new nodes to the existing node which uses 'insertEnd' method. So when 'ahead' is always null while passing parameter, each time a new node is added as `head==null`. So here 'insertEnd' can maximum perform recursion only one time creating a proper linked list.